# Getting BizTalk Active Host Instance

Tags: biztalk

My bizTalk application is deployed in active-passive cluster. I have a need to schedule the restart of one of the host instances (daily, every morning). How do I know how to get the active host instance since it could be either of them as failover may happen? I tried to stop/start service for server01 host instance but end up the host instance is running on server02. I tried to search online for vb script but can't find such a script.

Cheers
lyf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule taking the cluster resource offline and then online instead.

You might use
cluster.exe  RESOURCE  /offline
cluster.exe  RESOURCE  /online

Regards Martin Bring